# ORA-00942 error with subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey i have this select :

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
  FROM
    ( SELECT COUNT(LOGIN) AS COUNT_LOGIN,login FROM COMMENTS GROUP BY login
    ) LIST2
  WHERE COUNT_LOGIN=
    (SELECT MAX(COUNT_LOGIN) FROM LIST2
    )
  ) LIST1
INNER JOIN SYSTEM_USER
ON SYSTEM_USER.LOGIN=LIST1.login ;
```

And i get **ORA-00942 ** at this row `WHERE COUNT_LOGIN=(SELECT MAX(COUNT_LOGIN) FROM LIST2)`

Can somebody explain me why this subquery cant recognise LIST2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `subquery` with form of `having` clause not the `where` clause

```
SELECT login 
FROM COMMENTS 
GROUP BY login
HAVING COUNT(LOGIN) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT_LOGIN) 
                       FROM (SELECT login, COUNT(LOGIN) AS COUNT_LOGIN
                             FROM COMMENTS 
                             GROUP BY login
                            )
                      );
```

However, the *window* function will also helpful.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM SYSTEM_USER u
WHERE login = (SELECT Login
               FROM COMMENTS 
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Login) DESC
               FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
               );
```

Comment: yes i tried this. It is working when i copy- paste that select again instead of LIST2 , but is it possible to just use alias instead of copy-paste same select into that HAVING clause?

Answer (score 0):

To get login associated with most comments you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSTEM_USER su
WHERE su.login IN (SELECT Login
                   FROM Comments
                   ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Login) DESC
                   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY);
```

To avoid code duplication you could use CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT login, COUNT(LOGIN) AS cnt
  FROM COMMENTS 
  GROUP BY login
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM cte);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is not very well structured.
I understand you want to get all the logins which match with the max(count_login).
Why don't you try doing it this way (I haven't tested so the query could have some typo)

```
select cmt.*, su.*
from 
  (select max(count_login) max_count_login from comments) mcl
  join (select count(login) as count_login, login from comments group by login) cmt
    on mcl.max_count_login=cmt.count_login
  join system_user su
    on su.login=cmt.login
```

As the other users said, you can use better CTE in-memory tables or some windowed function, but if you are not that familiar with these options I think this solution will be easier to understand.